# Scala equivalent of java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, scala, arraylist

I am doing a project in Scala, but I am fairly new to the language, despite this I do have a Java background. I see that Scala doesn't have support for Java's ArrayList class, therefore I am wondering what is Scala's equivalent of it; and, if there is such an equivalent, I was wondering if there are any important differences between the Java and Scala versions of the class.

**EDIT:**  I'm not looking for a specific behaviour so much as an internal representation that being: data stored in an array, but in such a way that the whole array isn't visible, except for the part you use.

Comment: What would be the difference between the whole array being visible versus the part that you use?

Comment: @Daniel, the main difference to me is that ArrayList handles the size for me (i.e. if I don't know what it will be ahead of time or know it will change, I don't have to worry about allocating extra space and keeping track of how much space I actually use).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I can think of 3 more specific questions to address yours:

- What is Scala's default collection?
- What Scala collection has characteristics similar to `ArrayList`?
- What's a good replacement for `Array` in Scala?

So here are the answers for these:

### What is Scala's default collection?

Scala's equivalent of Java's `List` interface is the `Seq`. A more general interface exists as well, which is the `GenSeq` -- the main difference being that a `GenSeq` may have operations processed serially or in parallel, depending on the implementation.

Because Scala allows programmers to use `Seq` as a factory, they don't often bother with defining a particular implementation unless they care about it. When they do, they'll usually pick either Scala's `List` or `Vector`. They are both immutable, and `Vector` has good indexed access performance. On the other hand, `List` does very well the operations it does well.

### What Scala collection has characteristics similar to `ArrayList`?

That would be `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`.

### What's a good replacement for `Array` in Scala?

Well, the good news is, you can just use `Array` in Scala! In Java, `Array` is often avoided because of its general incompatibility with generics. It is a co-variant collection, whereas generics is invariant, it is mutable -- which makes its co-variance a danger, it accepts primitives where generics don't, and it has a pretty limited set of methods.

In Scala, `Array` -- which is still the same `Array` as in Java -- is invariant, which makes most problems go away. Scala accepts `AnyVal` (the equivalent of primitives) as types for its "generics", even though it will do auto-boxing. And through the "enrich my library" pattern, **ALL** of `Seq` methods are available to `Array`.

So, if you want a more powerful `Array`, just use an `Array`.

### What about a collection that shrinks and grows?

The default methods available to all collections all produce *new* collections. For example, if I do this:

```
val ys = xs filter (x => x % 2 == 0)
```

Then `ys` will be a *new* collection, while `xs` will still be the same as before this command. This is true no matter what `xs` was: `Array`, `List`, etc.

Naturally, this has a cost -- after all, you *are* producing a new collection. Scala's immutable collections are much better at handling this cost because they are *persistent*, but it depends on what operation is executed.

No collection can do much about `filter`, but a `List` has excellent performance on generating a new collection by prepending an element or removing the head -- the basic operations of a stack, as a matter of fact. `Vector` has good performance on a bunch of operations, but it only pays if the collection isn't small. For collections of, say, up to a hundred elements, the overall cost might exceed the gains.

So you can actually add or remove elements to an `Array`, and Scala will produce a *new* `Array` for you, but you'll pay the cost of a full copy when you do that.

Scala mutable collections add a few other methods. In particular, the collections that can increase or decrease size -- without producing a new collection -- implement the [`Growable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Growable) and [`Shrinkable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Shrinkable) traits. They don't guarantee good performance on these operations, though, but they'll point you to the collections you want to check out.

Comment: @astay13 I added one more section in answer to the comment you made about changing size.

Comment: @Daniel Can you say a little more about how Scala manages the cost of producing new immutable collections (ie, what it means to be "persistent"), or link to a good resource that discusses this?

Comment: @dhg Just look up persistent data structures on Stack Overflow, on Wikipedia, or a number of other different resources. It gets a bit off-topic for this question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "changing size is precisely what `ArrayList` does much worse than `LinkedList`"? Appending to an `ArrayList` is about an order of magnitude faster than appending to a `LinkedList` on large lists.

Comment: @FredOverflow Not amortized, it isn't. It might be faster as long as the backing array can fit new elements, but you'll hit a huge speed bump whenever it has to resize. And that's just append; try inserting an element anywhere else, or deleting an element from anywhere else.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/7OyDRW) is an online test that demonstrates `ArrayList` being about 3 times faster than `LinkedList`, despite the necessary reallocations. I had to reduce `N` to make it work online. With `N = 50000000` on my own machine, `ArrayList` is about 10 times faster than `LinkedList`. What results do you get on your machine? I would be really surprised if `LinkedList` was faster, because it needs more assignments per insertion (time), and each element needs an additional Node object (space).

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: [Here](http://ideone.com/MSGL2E) is a followup online test showing `ArrayList` being 12 times faster than `LinkedList` for inserts in the middle.  `LinkedList` only appears faster [when inserting near the beginning](http://ideone.com/eDksfH).

Comment: @FredOverflow While `LinkedList` needs more assignments per insert and additional space due to next/prev links, `ArrayList` needs to allocate a whole new array and copy all the contents from old to new when the backing array is filled. `LinkedList` never needs to copy data. A test with _one_ `N` is useless to measure amortized times -- try N from 0 to 50000000 in increments of 200 instead, and graph the results.

Comment: @MooingDuck You are using indexed access, and, thus, conflating actual insertion with lookup. Measure insertion at known element positions obtained through `ListIterator` -- that is, get a `listIterator`, travel to an arbitrary position, then measure insertion/deletion at that point through the `ListIterator`.

Comment: The cost of copying the contents from the old array to the new array is distributed among all elements: each time you insert an element, you pay one assignment *now*, and one assignment *later*.  Hence insertion is amortized constant time. Varying `N` is a completely unrelated issue.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: Look at the tests again, we did iterate `N` from 0 to 10000000, and  with increments of 1.   Even with _all of those copies_ `ArrayList` was 3x faster.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: growing an `ArrayList` which doubles in size each time it reallocates means that at most you do twice as many copies as there are elements -- or in other words, on average, each element is copied *twice*. No matter how much you grow the array, that is. And in return, you get a more efficient data structure with much better locality and cache characteristics. A linked list is virtually *never* faster. If you *never* need to look up elements, and you *never* need to iterate over the data structure, then a linked list *may* be faster. Otherwise? No.

Comment: @MooingDuck There's a final N in your code at the top, so you only do _one_ size, instead of benchmarking many sizes of N.

Comment: @FredOverflow Indeed, you are right. I did not consider well how many times each element must be copied on average.

Comment: @jalf How about prepending? How about inserting or deleting elements in the middle of a list as it is iterated over?

Comment: @FredOverflow I've decided to remove that, given that you've shown that append is indeed faster. I imagine that's not the case with prepending (which, curiously enough, is the fastest case of Scala's `List`), but when I wrote that I believed `LinkedList` was faster in _all_ size changes. Since it isn't...

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: in those cases, `ArrayList` will *usually* still be faster, because it is fewer allocations, less indirection, better memory locality. Keep in mind that inserting into the middle of a list *requires you to iterate to find the middle*. And that is *much* slower for a linked list. The rule of thumb is that "for some things, it's obvious that `ArrayList` is faster. For other things, it is surprising that `ArrayList` is faster". :)

Comment: This wasn't always the case, but the gap between CPU and memory performance has grown extremely wide. A random memory access is painfully slow, and linked lists are *all* random accesses. `ArrayList` (or any other dynamic array data structure) has virtually no random accesses. From a hardware point of view, that is a *huge* advantage, almost no matter which operations you perform on your data structure

Comment: @jalf But doesn't prepend requires ArrayList to always copy the whole array, vs single element creation with LinkedList?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: probably, yes (assuming `ArrayList` is implemented just as a single array internally). But the point is that, given how slow random memory accesses are these days, *even that* might not be enough to make a linked list competitive. (Of course, you should benchmark it before making important performance decisions). However, if you consistently need to prepend to the array, then you should probably use an entirely different data structure, rather than a linked list. Because those just suck universally, no matter which operations you perform on it.

Comment: Disclaimer: singly linked lists have their uses in languages which rely heavily on immutable data structures. But other than that? Stay clear of linked lists

Comment: @jalf Well, since you are talking about _languages_, Java's linked list have the problem that the link and the data are separately allocated, which is not necessarily true elsewhere. I note, for instance, that linux kernel uses doubly linked lists extensively.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: but for different reasons. (in C, a reallocation would invalidate existing pointers to data in the array/list. Linked lists don't suffer from that problem. And in a non-GC'ed language, a linked list can be a simple way to keep track of allocated resources, so you are able to free them again.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: you may find [this](http://bulldozer00.com/2012/02/09/vectors-and-lists/) interesting: Bjarne Stroustrup, "inventor" of C++, on the equivalent data structures in C++ (`vector` is basically an `ArrayList`, and `list` is a `LinkedList` -- note that in C++, the link and the data share the same allocation, so it should be *more* efficient than the Java implementation. And still, a linked list is just painfully, horribly slow

Comment: @jalf "A linked list is virtually never faster" What about that case - http://ideone.com/MMGwgZ ? It's a modification of the example above - removal of the half of a collection while iterating through it.

Comment: @MaxNevermind Sure, use a real microbenchmark framework and we can talk about it. That example is completely useless as a benchmark.

Comment: The ONLY time that a linked list is faster is when one needs to (frequently) do insertions/deletions *in the middle of a list, given a pointer to a list node*.  A good example are free lists used by `malloc()`.  In that case, a linked list is O(1) while an array is O(n).

Answer (score 24):

It's `ArrayBuffer` from `scala.collection.mutable`. You can find the scaladocs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what you should do because you haven't said what behavior of `ArrayList` you're interested in using. It's more useful to think in terms of which scala traits you want to take advantage of. Here's a good explanation: http://grahamhackingscala.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-convert-java-list-to-scala-list.html.

That said, you probably want some sort of `IndexedSeq`.