# How elements are stored in a collection?

Tags: java, scala, arraylist

I am familiar with Java collections are implemented and I am trying to understand how collections are implemented in Scala.

Do Scala's collections ultimately wrap Java collections? What is the equivalent of ArrayList in Scala? 
ArrayList in Java contains a variable `elementData` that holds an array [*]. Is this implementation similar in the equivalent class/trait in Scala? How growable collections in Scala are implemented?

Kind regards,
Alexandre

[*] 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287360/scala-equivalent-of-java-util-arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [overview document](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) for Scala collections.

Basically these are structures written directly in Scala and not wrappers around existing Java collections, although it is possible to wrap Java collections in the Scala API using the `JavaConverters` object.

Scala advocates immutable data structures which are easier to reason about when concurrency is involved, whereas the standard Java collections are mutable. The correspondence for `java.util.ArrayList` would probably be [`scala.collection.mutable.Buffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.Buffer%24). The default buffer implementation is `ArrayBuffer` which also uses an array internally which can grow dynamically.

Comment: `java.util.List` is an interface that best corresponds to the trait `Buffer`. `ArrayList` is a concrete collection -- I'd say it best corresponds to `ArrayBuffer`s in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

1) No, Scala collections are implemented separately from Java collections. However, there is a way to wrap Java collections to Scala collection interfaces, so that you can use Scala for-comprehensions and other methods on them.
The old way to convert from the Scala to Java API and vice versa is described [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html).

Nowadays, you can do it by importing `JavaConversions` as described in the link, and then calling `asJava` or `asScala` on the collection, depending which direction you need.

2) `ArrayList` is equivalent to the `ArrayBuffer` in terms of the complexity of Scala `apply` (Java `get`), `update` (Java `set`) and `+=` (Java `add`).

3) `ArrayBuffer` extends `ResizeableArray` utility class used by several other collections. As far as I remember, the private array field in that class is called `array0`, but the logic of manipulating it is the same as with `elementData`.

`ArrayBuffer`s guarantee amortized `O(1)` `+=` method, meaning that only occasionally an update will cost you `O(n)` when the underlying array needs to be resized to a bigger one.
Prepending elements is an `O(n)` operation, as well as inserting them in the middle.

In the `ArrayBuffer` operation the underlying array is never shrinked, i.e. once an array buffer grows to a certain size, and then all the elements are removed, it will still occupy the same amount of memory. This is true even if you call `clear` on it.

4) Growable collections are all collections that implement the trait `Growable`. This trait defines the method `+=` that adds an element to them. The exact semantics of this method depend on whether the collection is a set (in which case an element is added to the set), a sequence or a linked set/map (in which case there is order between the elements, so the element is just added to the end), or something else.
How growable collections are implemented depends from one collection to another. This is a good [overview for Scala collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html).

Comment: I have realized some benchmarks about collections, and it is frequent to see a very large proposition of collections that are left empty. Is there a reason why the private internal array (pointed by the `array` variable) is not lazily created?

Comment: `ArrayBuffer`s always waste 50% of memory in the worst case, and 25% in the average -- this can't be avoided. They also possibly allocate more memory than you need when created. When created the size of `array` is `16`. I guess the `lazy` wasn't used here because the cost of accessing a `lazy` field could be slightly higher than the cost of accessing a regular field, making `+=` slower (although I didn't benchmark this, just a guess). Note that if `16` is too big and you think it results in wasted memory, you can specify the initial size as the argument to `ArrayBuffer` ctor.